# Return Generic Type In Java

Tags: java, generics

I'm new to java and I'm trying to implement a generic method:

```
public static  <T> T login(String username,String password)
{
    //...
    return PageFactory.initElements(driver,T.class);
}
```

Here I want to  pass the generic type class, but when I tried `T.class` I'm getting the error:

`Cannot select from a type variable.`

Where I'm making the mistake?

Comment: Type erasure prevents you from doing `T.class`. Rethink your design, maybe pass a `Class<T>` argument to the method.

Comment: If you want to do this, you'll need to pass the class as a parameter; the use of generics will just avoid the cast of the returned object.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Due to [type erasure](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) at run time `T` is `java.lang.Object` so that is not an option. If have an instance of `T` on which to call `getClass()` though

```
public static  <T> T login(String username,String password, T obj) {
  // to get the class at run-time.
  return PageFactory.initElements(driver,obj.getClass());
}
```

or as others have already pointed out, you could just use

```
public static  <T> T login(String username,String password, Class<T> cls) {
  // to use the Class, passed from caller.
  return PageFactory.initElements(driver,cls);
}
```